# What do "inexquisitum" and "supramemorati" mean?

Tags: vocabulary, medieval-latin

In a medieval document I am reading the words "inexquisitum" and "supramemorati" appear. I do not know these words, can not find them on Google and they are not in my dictionary. Does anyone know what they mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- inexquisitum means ‘not having been examined in detail’ (cf. Du Cange. 1884. Glossarium mediae et infimae latinitatis, vol. 3, p. 377 (exquisitus) and 1885, vol. 4, p. 349 (inexquisitus).
- supramemoratus means 'above-mentioned’.